# Can't build react-native app after module upgrade: this package itself specifies a `main` module field that could not be resolved

Tags: javascript, react-native

Our react-native app uses the [Geodesy library](https://github.com/chrisveness/geodesy) and we're currently trying to upgrade from 1.1.3 to 2.2.0 as we require additional features.

When we try to build the app, we get the following error:

```
While trying to resolve module `geodesy` from file `redux\NMEA.js`, the package `node_modules\geodesy\package.json` was successfully found. However, this package itself specifies a `main` module field that could not be resolved (`node_modules\geodesy\index`). Indeed, none of these files exist:

  * `node_modules\geodesy\index(.native||.android.js|.native.js|.js|.android.json|.native.json|.json)`
  * `node_modules\geodesy\index\index(.native||.android.js|.native.js|.js|.android.json|.native.json|.json)`
```

The [migration info](https://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/geodesy-library-migrating-from-v1.html) says that it now requires ESM to load the modules, which I have installed, and I also installed the updated Geodesy package with `npm install geodesy esm` as instructed in the readme.

I've tried wiping my node_modules folder and reinstalling everything but this hasn't had any effect. Other that this, I'm at a total loss as to what could be causing the problem.